# Java text field won't update

Tags: java, swing

When I press the button, the text field doesn't update and every time it shows 20000.

The task is to choose from a combo box and then the text field will show you a number.

if STUDIO , Pb. show 10000
if F3 , pb shows 20000

```
String typoo = typo.getSelectedItem().toString();
int pbb = 0 ;
if (typoo == "Studio") {
    pbb = 10000;
} 
else if (typoo == "F3") {
    pbb = 20000;
}

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("UPDATE");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pb.setText(String.valueOf(pbb));
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to test for string equality, use the `equals()` method instead, for example: `if (typoo.equals("Studio")) {`. To ignore letter case you can use: `if (typoo.equalsIgnoreCase("studio")) {`.

Answer (score -1):

the if statements should be inside the actionPerformed() method
and use the function String.equals() to compare Strings